# Plotly python - pass opacity array to marker in Scatter3d object

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I would like to know if there is a way to pass opacity array into Scatter3d object. Below are my current findings on how to play around with the opacity:

- From the [Scatter3d documentation](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter3d-opacity), the `opacity` argument only accept a scalar value and apply to each marker.
- Also in plotly doc, I found that you can play with the `marker.color` rgba and use its alpha channel. Source: [this link](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter3d-marker-opacity)
- Also, there is [this link](https://plot.ly/~alex/455/four-ways-to-change-opacity-of-scatter-markers.embed) that shows 4 ways on how to change opacity. However all the methods including using the `marker.color` do not generate as to what my true intention is, which is each of marker point will take its opacity value from an array.

Below I attach together sample code to produce the sample surface:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from plotly import offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go

offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# read array for marker trace
markers = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izzatinvigour/test/master/plotly/markers.csv')
#markers.head()
# markers.opacity is the opacity array to pass

# read array for surface trace
surface = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izzatinvigour/test/master/plotly/surface.csv')
#surface.head()

# pivot surface to pass in plotly format
surfacepivot = surface.pivot(index='y', columns='x', values='z')
#surfacepivot

# plotly plot starts here

trace1 = go.Scatter3d(
    x = markers.x,
    y = markers.y,
    z = markers.z,
    mode = 'markers',
    name = 'markers',
)

trace2 = go.Surface(
    x = surfacepivot.columns,
    y = surfacepivot.index,
    z = surfacepivot.values,
    name = 'surface',
    opacity = 0.5
)

data = [trace1, trace2]

camera = dict(
    up=dict(x=0, y=0, z=1),
    center=dict(x=0, y=0, z=0),
    eye=dict(x=-1.25, y=-1.25, z=1.25)
)

layout = go.Layout(
    title='test',
    width=800,
    height=700,
    autosize=False,
    margin=dict(
        r=10, l=100,
        b=80, t=50,
    ),
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(
            title='x',
            gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            showbackground=True,
            backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            title='y',
            gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            showbackground=True,
            backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
        ),
        zaxis=dict(
            title='z',
            gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            showbackground=True,
            backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
        ),
        aspectratio = dict( x=1, y=1, z=0.7 ),
        aspectmode = 'manual',
        camera=camera
    )
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

offline.iplot(fig)
```

Tq in advance

Comment: I'd like to highlight that the code can be pasted and run in ipython notebook.